# How to clear contents of a jTable ?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a jTable and it's got a table model defined like this:

```
javax.swing.table.TableModel dataModel = 
     new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
tblCompounds.setModel(dataModel);
```

Does anyone know how I can clear its contents ? Just so it returns to an empty table ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
//private TableModel dataModel;
private DefaultTableModel dataModel;


void setModel() {
  Vector data = makeData();
  Vector columns = makeColumns();
  dataModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
  table.setModel(dataModel);
}

void reset() {
  dataModel.setRowCount(0);
}
```

i.e. your reset method tell the model to have 0 rows of data The model will fire the appropriate data change events to the table which will rebuild itself.

Comment: +1, (with a slight change), the TableModel interface does not have a setRowCount() method. That method is found in the DefaultTableModel class. I edited your sample code to use the DefaultTableModel, not the TableModel.

Comment: -100 This is not the correct answer if I understood the question.
In this question the most times we mean and we want to empty cells in the table and ΝΟΤ to have a TABLE WITHOUT CELLS!
Follow the answer of @Gebreigziabher Abadi below as the most correct, but changing the `dm.setValueAt("", i, j);`
with
`dm.setValueAt(null, i, j);`

Answer (score 12):

If you mean to remove the content but its cells remain intact, then:

```
public static void clearTable(final JTable table) {
   for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
          table.setValueAt("", i, j);
      }
   }
}
```

OK, if you mean to remove all the cells but maintain its headers:

```
public static void deleteAllRows(final DefaultTableModel model) {
    for( int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        model.removeRow(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i want to return the table to a state where its just got the column headers but no data in it

Comment: (virtual) -1 for the second part: as long as you know that the type of the model is DefaultTableModel, the correct method to call is setRowCount(0).

Answer (score 4):

```
    //To clear the Contents of Java JTable

    DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) JTable1.getModel();

    for (int i = 0; i < dm.getRowCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dm.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            dm.setValueAt("", i, j);
        }
    }
```

Comment: judging by the fact that the OP accepted an answer that _removed all rows_ emptying the _cell content_ doesn't seem what s/he wanted to achieve :-) And if that were the goal, setting the content to an empty string is not emptying it and might blow up in your face (if the model expects another type): so better null the content.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options:

1. Create a `new DefaultTableModel()`, but remember to re-attach any listeners.
2. Iterate over the `model.removeRow(index)` to remove.
3. Define your own model that wraps a List/Set and expose the `clear` method.

Comment: DefaultTableModel _has_ a clear method - just named differently :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant that you want to clear all the cells in the jTable and make it just like a new blank jTable.
For an example, if your table contains 40 raws, you can do following.

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)this.jTable.getModel();
model.setRowCount(0);
model.setRowCount(40);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the trivial methods is to use the following option.

```
dataModel.setRowCount(0);
```

dataModel is the model which you would like clear the content on

However, it is not optiomal solution.

Answer (score -1):

Another easy answer:

```
defaultTableModel.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
```

Comment: no, that's completely wrong: never-ever change the data under the feet of the model, instead use model api