# How do you change data in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

## How do you change data in jtable in java

I have a joptionpane that takes input and puts it into my jtable (I'm using a Object[][] for the array and abstract table model). I want to know how to erase all the data in the table and insert new data. So for example I would enter in a few strings into the jtable then I want to say click a button and have all the data in the table be removed and be able to add new strings from the first row and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear contents of a jTable ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879610/how-to-clear-contents-of-a-jtable)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `TableModel` and apply it to the `JTable` using `JTable#setModel`

For example...

```
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0));
// Columns is an array of column names you have previously 
// specified...
```

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details...