# Refresh the JTable?

Tags: java, database, swing, jdbc, jtable

Can anyone explain why this (see pictures below) happens and anyway to fix it?

```
public class DataVector 
{
Connection connect = null;
Statement statement = null;
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();

public DataVector() {}
public void GetData (JTable table)
{                 
    String []colsName = {"MÃ NHÂN VIÊN", "HỌ NHÂN VIÊN", "TÊN NHÂN VIÊN", "GIỚI TÍNH", "NĂM SINH", "TRÌNH ĐỘ", "SỐ ĐT", "ĐỊA CHỈ"};
    tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(colsName);  // đặt tiêu đề cột cho tableModel
    connectSQL();                           
    updateData(view());// gọi hàm view để truy suất dữ liệu sau đó truyền cho hàm updateData để đưa dữ liệu vào tableModel và hiện lên Jtable trong Frame 
    table.setModel(tableModel);
}
public void updateData(ResultSet result)
{
    String []colsName = {"MÃ NHÂN VIÊN", "HỌ NHÂN VIÊN", "TÊN NHÂN VIÊN",   "GIỚI TÍNH", "NĂM SINH", "TRÌNH ĐỘ", "SỐ ĐT", "ĐỊA CHỈ"};
    tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(colsName); // Đặt tiêu đề cho bảng theo các giá trị của mảng colsName
    try {
        while(result.next())
        { // nếu còn đọc tiếp được một dòng dữ liệu
            String rows[] = new String[8];
            rows[0] = result.getString(1); // lấy dữ liệu tại cột số 1 (ứng với mã hàng)
            rows[1] = result.getString(2);
            rows[2] = result.getString(3);
            rows[3] = result.getString(4);
            rows[4] = result.getString(5);
            rows[5] = result.getString(6);
            rows[6] = result.getString(7);// lấy dữ liệu tai cột số 2 ứng với tên hàng
            rows[7] = result.getString(8);
            tableModel.addRow(rows); // đưa dòng dữ liệu vào tableModel để   hiện thị lên jtable
            //mỗi lần có sự thay đổi dữ liệu ở tableModel thì Jtable sẽ tự động update lại trên frame
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {}       
}               
public void connectSQL(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbc?     useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
            System.out.println("Kết nối thành công");
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}       
}  
public ResultSet view(){
    ResultSet result = null;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM nhanvien";
    try {
        Statement statement = (Statement) connect.createStatement();
        return statement.executeQuery(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {}
    return result;
}
}
```

This is my code to show the Database to JTable.

```
public void Add () throws SQLException
{          
    String sql;
    String mNV = STF.TX1.getText();
    String hNV = STF.TX2.getText();
    String tNV = STF.TX3.getText();
    String gT = SB.TX4.getText();
    String nS = STF.TX5.getText();
    String tD = STF.TX6.getText();
    String sDT = STF.TX7.getText();
    String dC = STF.TX8.getText();
    sql = "INSERT INTO `nhanvien` "
         + "(`MÃ NV`, `HỌ NV`, `TÊN NV`, `GIỚI TÍNH`, `NĂM SINH`, `TRÌNH ĐỘ`, `SỐ ĐT`, `ĐỊA CHỈ`) "
         + "VALUES ('"+mNV+"', '"+hNV+"', '"+tNV+"', '"+gT+"', '"+nS+"', '"+tD+"', '"+sDT+"', '"+dC+"');";
    AD.Add(sql);
}
```

And this is the add button.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ed6v.png]
Before add.

[image]
After add.

Comment: `"Can anyone explain why this happen and anyway to fix it ?"` -- why *what* happened? Please tell the details.

Comment: I think it's because it repeats the contents? I'm not so sure since I can't read Vietnamese.

Comment: I think you need to use this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879610/how-to-clear-contents-of-a-jtable

Comment: Also, method names should not start with an upper case character.